# Criar um controller para fazer uma requisição do tipo GET

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou criando uma API simples com node que faço uma postagem de noticias, nisso estou utilizando o express para criar as minhas rotas da minha aplicação, eu ja consegui criar um controller que faz a postagem das minhas noticias, mas não sei como faria um controller para fazer um get..alguem poderia me ajudar??

Comment: Se já fez uma rota para um `POST`, qual a dificuldade em criar uma para o método `GET`? Poste o seu código para ficar mais fácil de demostrar o que precisa ser feito nele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se voce está usando o express, deveria usar a função get e apontar para uma função do seu controller que lista as suas notícias. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send( #COLOCA AQUI A FUNÇÃO QUE LISTA SUAS NOTICIAS ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código da minha rota `GET`:

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../Models/index');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('timeline', (req, res) => {
    res.send({ req.params.User});
});
```

mas pelo que eu vi dessa forma não seria o correto a se fazer certo?